# Change output filename when running a command in a loop

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I am using the Tracer software package (https://github.com/Teichlab/tracer).
The program is invoked as followed:

`tracer assemble [options] <file_1> [<file_2>] <cell_name> <output_directory>`

The program runs on a single dataset and the output goes to `/<output_directory>/<cell_name>`

What I want to do now is run this program on multiple files. To do so this is what I do:

```bash
for filename in /home/tobias/tracer/datasets/test/*.fastq
do
echo "Processing $filename file..."
python tracer assemble --single_end --fragment_length 62 --fragment_sd 1 $filename Tcell_test output; 
done
```

This works in priciple, but as `cell_name` is static, every iteration overwrites the output from the previous iteration. How do I need to change my script in order to give the output folder the name of the input file?

For example: Input filename is `tcell1.fastq`. For this cell_name should be `tcell1`. Next file is `tcell2.fastq` and cell_name should be `tcell2`, and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will do it, in bash, if I understand correctly -

```bash
for filename in /home/tobias/tracer/datasets/test/*.fastq
do
  echo "Processing $filename file..."
  basefilename="${filename##*/}"   #<--- 
  python tracer assemble --single_end --fragment_length 62 --fragment_sd 1 "$filename" "${basefilename%.fastq}" output;
  #                                                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
done
```

`${filename##*/}` removes the part up to the last `/`, and `${basefilename%.fastq}` removes the `.fastq` at the end.

Comment: @baracus37 Glad to hear it, and welcome to the site!

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood the library you use writes output to predefined (non configurable) directory

Let's call it `output_dir`.
At each iteration you should rename the output directory.

So your code should be something like this (pseudo code)

```
for filename in /home/tobias/tracer/datasets/test/*.fastq
   do
     echo "Processing $filename file..."
     python tracer assemble --single_end --fragment_length 62 --fragment_sd 1 $filename Tcell_test output; 
     rename  output_dir , each_file + "_output_dir"
   done
```